# Retrieving table content data in ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, controller, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am creating an ember application which gets data from servlet and prints it in a table format.. the table looks like this

```
Capacity Price  RoomType    RoomNo  Action
6        4150   suite         93    Select
2        1579   villa          5    Select
1        1526   villa          1    Select
```

When I click select I need to get the value in the room no.
I tried creating a tracked variable and updating the value but got stuck, so any idea how I can do it in ember would be appreciated. I found an article which uses jQuery to do the same but I don't know how to add jQuery to an ember application.

Myy handlebar file

```
{{#if this.request.isPending}}
  loading data...
{{/if}}
<main class="conttainer mt-5 ">

<container class="cond">
<table border="1|0" class = "tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><td>Capacity</td></th>
      <th><td>Price</td></th>
      <th><td>RoomType</td></th>
      <th><td>RoomNo</td></th>
      <th><td>Action</td></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   
    {{#each this.result as |row|}}    
      <tr>
        {{#each-in row as |key value|}}
          <td>{{value}}</td>
          
        {{/each-in}}
        <td><button  class = "btn-test" {{on "click" (this.getroomno) {{value}}>Select</button></td>//--> wrong decleration yet i dont know how to access the roomno column
        
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
</container>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><h5>room number</h5></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>{{this.room}}</td></tr>//---> i have to show the value here
    <tr><td><b>Enter the Start Date</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type = "date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id = "sdate" value = "2022-07-01" min = "2022-07-01" max = "2022-07-31"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Enter the End Date</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type = "date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" id = "edate" value = "2022-07-01" min = "2022-07-01" max = "2022-07-31"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type = "button" {{action "get"}}>submit</button></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

</main>
```

My controller file

```
class RequestState {
  @tracked value;
  @tracked error;

  get isPending() {
    return !this.error && !this.value;
  }
}

export default class RoomselectController extends Controller {
  @service router;
  @tracked room =0;
  getroomno(value){
    var that = this;
    console.log(value);
    that.room = value;
    console.log(that.room)
  }

  @use request = resource(({ on }) => {
    const state = new RequestState();
    var dis = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/hotelres/My',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){ 
        console.log(response)
        if(response == 0){
          dis.transitionToRoute("error");
        }else{
          state.value = response
        }
      },
      error: (xhr, status, error) =>
        (state.error = `${status}: ${xhr.statusText}`),
    });

    return state;
  });

  get result() {
    return this.request.value || [];
  }
```

I need to render the room number when the select button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your row, I see:

```
<td><button class="btn-test" {{on "click" (this.getroomno) {{value}}>Select</button></td>
```

which would *invoke* `this.getroomno` before passing a "handler" to the on click event listener. (and then `{{value}}` should be a syntax error? because there are two opening `{{` and one closing `}}`

For more information on this syntax, see: [this cheatsheet](https://cheatsheet.glimmer.nullvoxpopuli.com/docs/templates)

I *think* you want something more like:

```
<td>
  <button 
    class="btn-test" 
    {{on "click" (fn this.getroomno row)>
    Select
  </button>
</td>
```

Docs on `fn` are [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/#toc_getting-used-to-action-on-and-fn)

fn partially applies `row` to `getroomno`, so when invoked, `getroomno` will be passed the row and the click event will be the last argument (if needed)